# How to use requestAccessToEntityType method in Swift iOS 8

Tags: swift, ios8, eventkit, ekeventstore

I'm trying to get a list of events by using `EKEventStore` using Swift in iOS8, and the documentation is not updated yet as far as I can tell.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
let eventStore =  EKEventStore()

eventStore.requestAccessToEntityType(EKEntityType(), EKEventStoreRequestAccessCompletionHandler(Bool(), NSError(){}))
```

This is the error I get:

`'EKEventStoreRequestAccessCompletionHandler' is not constructible with '(Bool, NSError)`

Do you know how can I use the method or the handler correctly in Swift?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this please:

```
func handler(granted: Bool, error: NSError!) {
    // put your handler code here
}

@IBAction func click(sender: AnyObject) {
    let eventStore = EKEventStore()

    // 'EKEntityTypeReminder' or 'EKEntityTypeEvent'
    eventStore.requestAccessToEntityType(EKEntityTypeEvent, completion: handler) 
}
```

Another variant is:

```
@IBAction func click(sender: AnyObject) {
    let eventStore = EKEventStore()

    // 'EKEntityTypeReminder' or 'EKEntityTypeEvent'
    eventStore.requestAccessToEntityType(EKEntityTypeEvent, completion: {
        granted, error in

        // put your handler code here
        })
}
```