# Error "Use of unresolved identifier 'EKEntityTypeEvent'" trying to access Calendar

Tags: ios, swift, eventkit

I'm trying to get access to a user's calendars via EventKit using Swift 2. In digging around online, I've found a [few](http://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/05/14/beginners-guide-to-eventkit-in-swift-requesting-permission/#checking-calendar-authorization) [examples](http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/add-event-calendar-tutorial-ios8-swift) showing similar implementations to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24697149/424303) on another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24692605/how-to-use-requestaccesstoentitytype-method-in-swift-ios-8).

The error I keep hitting is

> Use of unresolved identifier 'EKEntityTypeEvent'

In my viewDidLoad() -

```
let eventStore = EKEventStore()

switch EKEventStore.authorizationStatusForEntityType(EKEntityTypeEvent) {        
case .Authorized:
    insertEvent(eventStore)
case .Denied:
    print("Access denied")
case .NotDetermined:
    eventStore.requestAccessToEntityType(EKEntityTypeEvent, completion:
        {[weak self] (granted: Bool, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if granted {
                self!.insertEvent(eventStore)
            } else {
                print("Access denied")
            }
        })
default:
    print("Case Default")
}
```

Any ideas on this error?

I'm running El Capitan / XCode 7 Beta 3.

Comment: I don't have access to Xcode 7 in this moment, but I assume that `EKEntityTypeEvent` should be `.Event`.

Comment: @MartinR thanks for comment. Could you elaborate on what you mean?

Comment: What he is saying is that you should write `.Event` instead of `EKEntityTypeEvent`.

Comment: Gotcha - that returns "Could not find member 'Event'"

Comment: note the `.` in front!?

Comment: @luk2302 yep I included the .

Comment: okay, then you have to use `EKEntityType.Event` for some reason...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, there are mainly two things wrong here - the first has already been discussed in the comments.

First: use `.Event` or `EKEntityType.Event` instead of the `EKEntityTypeEvent`.

Second: change the declaration of the completion handler to accept a `NSError?` instead of `NSError!` because [the actual completion handler](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKEventStoreClassRef/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/tdef/c:@T@EKEventStoreRequestAccessCompletionHandler) is defined this way.

Comment: requestAccessToEntityType should fire the request to access calendar events correct? While it does compile, no request notification appears.  Thoughts?

Comment: @Emile no idea, sry :/ you might want to ask a different question for that issue...